# pg_prepare() failing when named variables are used

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm using following query:

```
$result = pg_prepare($this->getConn(), "querytemp1", "SELECT * FROM tb001_empregado \n WHERE nu_usuario = :matricula");
```

That's a working query if I manually add a nu_usuario value. But when this code is executed, I get following error:

```
 Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" LINE 2: WHERE nu_usuario = :matricula ^ in ********* on line ***
```

`$result` returns false.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Postgres 8.4, maybe it still doesn't support named variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$1`, `$2`, etc. `:variable` is only available with PDO/Postgres.

Comment: Could you provide me an aexmple of how to do it with PDO/Postgres?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009263/how-to-make-dynamic-postgres-prepared-statements-in-php Here there is an example of pg_prepare() using named variable.

Comment: @Hikari: all I'm seeing in the link you provided is $1, $2, etc. For examples of PDO, they're the same as for MySQL and other databases: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009263/how-to-make-dynamic-postgres-prepared-statements-in-php#16840877 I forgot to get post ID

Comment: Ah, I see it now. But are you sure that actually works and shouldn't have been down voted because it's incorrect? :-) I ask, because to the best of my knowledge `pg_prepare()` is equivalent to issuing a normal `PREPARE` statement, and named parameters do not work in the latter case.

Comment: I dont see it downvoted. But I suppose it's incorrect yeah :/ I'll try to learn PDO

Answer (score 2):

Check manual page for `pg_prepare()`.

You have to use `$1`, `$2`, etc. for parameters.

Comment: Numbers work, I wanna use names to avoid errors in their order.